# R extracting numbers from a series .out files

Tags: r, extract

I have 35 files that are error output from another program. I can read them into R but I'm not sure how to extract a single value from all files.

```
ldf <- list() # creates a list
listcsv <- dir(pattern = "error*") # creates the list of all the csv files in the directory
for (k in 1:length(listcsv)){
ldf[[k]] <- read.csv(listcsv[k],header=FALSE,fill=TRUE,skip=4)
}
```

This code gives me the last line of each file but still has text and I just want the numbers added into a list that I can plot.

Image of one output file, they are all the same:
[image: Image of one output file, they are all the same.]

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use the str_match function in the stringr package.

```
ldf<-list()
ldf[[1]]<-"Program exectution time: 6.19793 seconds"
ldf[[2]]<-"Program exectution time: 9.19793 seconds"

library(stringr)
output<-str_match(ldf, "[.0-9]*[.0-9]")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `strsplit` command and split at the whitespace positions (works inversly to the `paste` command).

```
x <- c("Program execution time: 6.19793 seconds")
strsplit(x, split = " ")
```

You can combine it with `as.numeric` to convert the string to a number.